# Convert a basic site to a full site in SharePoint 2010?

Tags: publishing-site, site-collection, powershell

I'm not quite sure of the best way to ask this.  I have some sites that I would call basic sites (SharePoint Foundation 2010 was WSS) that have very basic functionality and then I have other sites that have full SharePoint Enterprise 2010 functionality (publishing, more web parts, etc).

Is it possible to convert these basic WSS sites to full SharePoint Enterprise 2010 sites?

If so, PowerShell would be handy since then I could script it up to convert all of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly all you need to do is enable the appropriate features on the site collection.

You can do this manually from the Site Actions / Site setting menu or using PowerShell.

Comment: I get what you're saying about adding the features.  My "basic" site only had "Metadata Navigation and Filtering" and "Team Collaboration Lists" enabled while the "full" site also had "SharePoint Server Enterprise Site features" enabled.  I enabled that and I sill have a limited number of webparts I'm able to choose from.  For example it doesn't show the Default and Filters web part Categories.

Comment: Did you look at the features on both the Site Collection and the Site level? They are separate.

Comment: Perfect!  That is what I was missing.  By enabling the SharePoint Server Enterprise Site features on both the Site Collection and the site the site now has all of the capabilities of SharePoint Enterprise.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you have already upgraded WSS to SharePoint Foundation 2010. If not this is the first thing that you need to do.

The next is that your SharePoint Server must be upgraded to SharePoint Enterprise Edition.

You must then enable / activate the features on the site collection.